On the relationship between relative interior and core of a set in convex analysis
I encountered what seems to be the same theorem about the relationship between the relative interior and core of a set in two different books:

In "First-Order Methods in Optimization" by Amir Beck



In "Convex analysis and nonlinear optimization: theory and examples" by Borwein et al.

However, the conditions stated in these books appear to be different. This leads me to the following questions:

What is the precise relationship between the relative interior and the core of a set C?

Under what conditions are they equal?

Could someone provide some intuition or geometric interpretation of their relationship?

Are there any key references in the literature that discuss this relationship in detail?


I would appreciate any insights or references that could help clarify this relationship.

(In this post, $C$ is a convex set.)
The notion of relative interior is motivated by the observation that if $C$ is contained in a subspace, then everything related to $C$ can be either done in the subspace (or in its orthogonal complement if $E$ is a Hilbert space).
For finite-dimensional $E$, the relative interior of $C$ is always non-empty. If $int(C) \ne \emptyset$ then $int(C) = relint(C)$.
The core is a generalization of the interior, in the sense that $int(C) \subseteq core(C)$. They are equal (1) if $E$ is finite-dimensional, or (2) if $C$ is closed, $E$ is Banach by the Baire category theorem.
In this sense core and relative interior are relaxations of interior. In my opinion, relative interior is useful for finite-dimensional settings, while core is more useful for infinite-dimensional world.
Not sure if this answers your question.

Can you explain why the interior and core are equal in finite dimensional spaces? I seem to have seen examples where they are not equal in finite dimensional spaces. For examle, in $R^2$, let $D={(x,y)|y=0 \quad or \quad  |y|\geq x^2}$, then $0 \in core(D) / int(D)$

I wrote the answer with convex sets in mind.
